# Create Terminal for android phone

Tags: c#, android

I want to make a terminal for phones in android studio. I want the input method not the commands. So I need to:

- Create input method
- Check input Text

For example in C# code (Console Class):

```
while(; true;)
{
        Console.Write(":>");
        String inputText = Console.ReadLine();
        switch(inputText)
        {
            case "Hello":
                //do something
            break;
            case "Hi":
               //do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is question?

Comment: How to make a terminal?